# Subclassing UIViewController, viewDidLoad called repeatedly

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, subclass

I subclassed `UIViewController` as `STViewController` and noticed that classes inheriting from `STViewController` have their `viewDidLoad` method being called repeatedly. Ultimately crashing the app. `STViewController` is basically a blank implementation at this point. I am subclassing as shown below:

```
#import "STViewController.h"

@interface WelcomeViewController : STViewController {
```

STViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface STViewController : UIViewController
{
}
@end
```

STViewController.m

```
#import "STViewController.h"


@implementation STViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadView
{
    // Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
@end
```

viewDidLoad() from WelcomeViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // hide the buttons
    [[self signUp] setHidden: YES];
    [[self logIn] setHidden: YES];
}
```

Comment: Can we see the 'blank implementation? (STViewController)

Comment: How does the `viewDidLoad` implementation look in `WelcomeViewController` and `STViewController`?

Comment: Updated post with those details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are overriding `loadView`, but your implementation is empty, and you're not assigning a view. Remove the `loadView` override.

From [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView) (emphasis mine):

> You should never call this method directly. The view controller calls
>   this method when the view property is requested but is currently nil.
>   If you create your views manually, you must override this method and
>   use it to create your views. If you use Interface Builder to create
>   your views and initialize the view controller—that is, you initialize
>   the view using the initWithNibName:bundle: method, set the nibName and
>   nibBundle properties directly, or create both your views and view
>   controller in Interface Builder—then you must not override this
>   method.
>
> The default implementation of this method looks for valid nib
>   information and uses that information to load the associated nib file.
>   If no nib information is specified, **the default implementation creates
>   a plain UIView object and makes it the main view**.
>
> If you override this method in order to create your views manually,
>   **you should do so and assign the root view of your hierarchy to the
>   view property**. (The views you create should be unique instances and
>   should not be shared with any other view controller object.) Your
>   custom implementation of this method should not call super.

Comment: Really Amazing! There was no hint logged in the console.!